# Html.ActionLink cannot be styled

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, styling

I wanted to combine my CSS and Bootstrap with MVC but I cannot style my links properly. As far as I know I need to use  @Html.ActionLink to redirect my webpage. Is there a way to style it?

Everything works while using pure CSS:

```
<div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">LIBRARY</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

This is my MVC:

```
<div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/Index">
                @Html.ActionLink("Library", "Index", "MyTemplate", null, new { @class = "mx-auto order-0" })
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

I have also tested this on MVC but still does not style:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Library", "Index", "MyTemplate", null, new { @class = "mx-auto order-0" })
```

My index.cshtml file looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public class MyTemplateController : Controller
    {
        // GET: MyTemplate
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View("About");
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View("Contact");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <title>@ViewBag.title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/style.css">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("head", false)

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="background-color: #333;text-align: center;">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-1 order-md-0 dual-collapse2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Books
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New books</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Recommended books</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Available books</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Categories
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Genres</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Formats</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "MyTemplate")
                    
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/About">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "MyTemplate")
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "MyTemplate")
        @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "MyTemplate", null, new { @class = "mx-auto order-0" })

        <div class="mx-auto order-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/Index">
                @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "MyTemplate", null, new { @class = "mx-auto order-0" })
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <form class="form-inline d-none d-lg-block justify-content-center md-form form-sm mt-0" style="padding: 5px">
                    <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Search"
                           aria-label="Search">
                </form>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
        @RenderBody()
    </main>


    <footer>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 social">
                <a href="https://github.com/V1co?tab=repositories" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/r-pawlowski/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="mailto:rafal.pawlowski1993@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/v1coprivate" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="d-none d-md-inline col-md-4">
                <p class="me"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-md-inline col-md-4">
                <p class="me">Rafal Pawlowski &#169;2020</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately styling does not apply. I know I could do @style and style it this way but I wanted all style to be applied in style.css not hardcoding it in each class because it will look bad in my code. Please help

Comment: In the client-side code, what is the resulting HTML of the link?

Comment: I have edited my post. I have pasted controller code and index.cshtml code

Comment: Okay, but what is the HTML of the link in your client-side code?  It sounds like you're saying the `class` attribute isn't being applied, correct?  When you confirmed that, what was the exact HTML?

Comment: HTML file has been added. Refresh the page to see full code. Please not that I have added @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "MyTemplate") 3 times each time differently to see if one of these somehow works but they do not style

Comment: You're missing a critical debugging step here... actually examining your output.  The server-side code which *generates* that output is not what you need to be looking at.  In your browser, look at the "View Source" option.  Examine the *actual HTML* that this is generating.  Basically, you need to confirm whether or not your assumption about the problem is even true before trying to solve that assumption.

Comment: an `@Html.Action` renders as an `<a>` tag... you are putting and a tag inside an a tag which is invalid

Comment: @David Because the questioner mentioned in comments the filetype .cshtml, I added two asp.net tags for make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this HTML:

```
<div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">LIBRARY</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Then your MVC should look like this:

```
<div class="mx-auto order-0">
            @Html.ActionLink("Library", "Index", "MyTemplate", null, new { @class = "mx-auto order-0" })
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

You are warapping your `Html.ActionLink` (which renders as an anchor tag) in another a tag. And you cannot have a link inside a link.

Alternativly, you could do this also (notice the href of the a tag is the Razor Url helper):

```
<div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="@Url.Action("Index", "MyTemplate")">LIBRARY</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1st solution did not worked but second did! Thank you a lot!